# How to Improve ASUS RT-AC68U Wireless Speeds

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, speed

I recently upgraded my wireless router to an ASUS RT-AC68U. I pay for Google Fiber's gigabit speed so I think I should be able to get decent wireless speeds with this router. The problem is that I'm seeing an sporadic download speeds; sometimes I see 90+ Mbps speeds but most of the time I see between 10-20Mbps download speeds (and sometimes my speed tests fail during the upload test). Even testing in the same room as the router produces these inconsistent results.

I have the router set up Access Point mode, but I'm wondering if there's something else I need to do to promote a more consistent wireless speed. I'm not very experienced with router settings so I don't know what to do. My Google searches haven't really found anything helpful. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of links in the chain you're trying to diagnose.  Some things to keep in mind are that servers don't have unlimited upload speeds any more than you do and many (ime) top out around 20ish outside of the Microsofts and Blizzards of the world and your experience will depend on the current server load.  That being said, I've found that [Speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/) tends to give consistent results.

I don't know how Google gets the data to your home, but if the fiber doesn't come all the way into your house, there's a chance for a bottle-neck outside of your control.

You should also always look for firmware upgrades for your router if it is not performing as well as you'd like.  You should also be sure you have the latest drivers for your NIC.

You might consider how many devices are connected to your router (XBox, phone, tablet, latptop, TV, etc.) perhaps a sanity check would be to temporarily remove the other devices and use just your laptop.

You might also consider switching to the 5GHz band on the router as generally fewer devices will use that spectrum.  Check the position of the antennae as that really does affect signal strength.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I use Speedtest.net for my speed testing too. The fiber does come all the way to the house and into their own special modem/router, so that shouldn't be an issue (speed testing a wired connection produces consistent ~950-990 Gbps speeds). Firmware is also up to date. I have not disconnected every device when speed testing, so I'll try that. I have one or two devices that aren't 5GHz compatible, so I don't think I can do that...